# UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps not called when using React 16.3.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I followed the advice in https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#gradual-migration-path and after upgrading to React 16.3.2 I wanted to rename all our soon to be deprecated lifecycle methods to their `UNSAFE_` equivalents.

However I noticed that `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps` is not called at all. When I change it back to `componentWillReceiveProps` it works. Any ideas why?

```
class Chart extends React.Component<ChartProps> {
  chartContainer: SVGSVGElement;
  tooltip: HTMLDivElement;
  xScale: ScaleBand<string>;
  yScale: ScaleLinear<number, number>;

  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: Props) {
    ...
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the issue. `react-dom` package needs to be upgraded to 16.3.2 version as well.